# QImageReader::text() does not work properly

Tags: qt, exif, qimage

I need to read image description (`QImage::text()`) without reading whole image. I used QImageReader, but its behaviour is very strange. It does not return `text()` or `textKeys()` but `QImage` does.

Example code:

```
QImageReader imageReader(filename,0);
QImage image;
bool ok=imageReader.read(&image);
qDebug() << "KEYS_READER: " << imageReader.textKeys() << "\n";
qDebug() << "KEYS_IMAGE: " << image.textKeys() << "\n";
```

When I try to load data from image which has one text key it prints in the debug window:

```
KEYS:  () 
KEYS0:  ("UVFI")
```

But I need to retrieve keys without reading the whole image data.

Comment: It seems that the current Qt API does not support this. The keys come from image header data, and there's no separate method exposed to read just the headers without reading the image :(

Comment: Qt API supports this. I found that my QImageIOHandler did not supported properly Description feature. I fixed it and it works.

Comment: May I ask how exactly you implemented the Description feature? Is your code online somewhere? I would appreciate that "example code". :)